# instantiating a new object delete already drawn shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-development, pong

Im coding an OOP html canvas pong game ,my paddle code is this

```js
class Paddle extends Canvas {
    #width
    #height
    #y
    #index
    #x
    constructor(id,i) {
        super(id);
        this.#index=i;
        this.#y = 0;
        this.resize();
    }
    draw() {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.rect(this.#x, this.#y, this.#width, this.#height);
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.closePath();
    }
    update() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.draw();
    }
    resize() {
        this._resize();
        this.#width = Math.pow(this.canvas.width, 1 / 2) * 2;
        this.#height = this.canvas.height / 4;
        if(this.#index === 0){
            console.log("left")
            this.#x=0;
        }else{
            console.log("right")
            this.#x=this.canvas.width - this.#width;
        }
        this.draw();
    }
    set y(value) {
        this.#y = value;
        this.update();
    }
}
```

when I instantiating a new paddle object it draws the new paddle and deletes the other paddle

the problem can be spotted with :

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    let rightPaddle = new Paddle('paddle',1);
},1000)
let leftPaddle = new Paddle('paddle',0);
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnHoY.gif)

any ideas on what causes the problem

[js fiddle showcasing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/Talel_kraiem/qxuynzhm/5/)

Comment: you should post your full code or make a jsfiddle or codepen. The fact that you are extending canvas is suspicious I'd say to start, and then after that you are giving them both the same ID, which seems frong. But without knowing the rest of your code there's no way to know.

Comment: @RobLouie added js fiddle link to showcase my code , thanks for pointing this to me

Comment: Your paddle shouldn't be responsible of clearing the context, do it in another place/component, that will get its job done first thing at each frame.

Answer (score 0):

The base answer to your question is that changing a canvas's size will cause it to be cleared. You are changing your canvas size all over the place, which is erasing anything on it.

I would also say you're maybe going overkill with inheritance which is making things more confusing. Also, rather than handling the scaling of the canvas manually, you could make things much easier on yourself by setting a fixed canvas size and then letting css scale the canvas up. This way you don't have to worry about resizing anything you draw. Something like this:

```
<canvas width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>

canvas {
  width: min(100vw, calc(100vh * 16/9));
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
```

This will make your canvas always render at 1080p and it will still scale up as big as your screen can go while maintaining a 16:9 aspect ratio. If you don't like this you can still do your resize logic, just handle it separately. I'd also say just use one canvas and draw everything to it.

Now you can use fixed sizes for everything and do something like:

```
class Paddle {
  #width = 80;
  #height = 140;
  #x = 0;
  #y = 0;

  constructor(xPosition) {
    this.#x = xPosition;
  }

  moveUp() {
    this.#y--;
  }

  moveDown() {
    this.#y++;
  }

  draw(context) {
    context.fillRect(this.#x, this.#y, this.#width, this.#height);
  }
}

const context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

const paddle1 = new Paddle(0);
const paddle2 = new Paddle(1840);

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
  // determine if use presses up or down and call moveUp or moveDown on paddles
  // determine score and update Hud
  
  hud.draw(context);
  paddle1.draw(context);
  paddle2.draw(context);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

And thats all you have to do, it's a bit simplified to show the concept of keeping things more separate though. If you want to manually handle resize, handle that completely separately by using your resize callback and resizing your canvas, paddles, and hud there. It will still clear the canvas but on the next frame your draw() function will redraw it and you'll be good.